# ajax call to a different action doesn't work in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 application I have a controller, items_controller.rb, which has an action "new":

```
def new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

In the new.html.erb I have the following code which initiates an ajax call to the same action "new" when I click on "#aaa".

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aaa").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/items/new",
        data: {},
        async: true,
        dataType: 'script'
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is new.js.erb:

```
$("#test_tag").html("qqq");
```

This code works perfectly fine and when I click on "#aaa", it modifies the html of "#test_tag" to "qqq" as expected. Now if I just try to do the same using another action in my items_controller.rb say "htmlupdate" it won't work. All I do is change the url in the ajax call (in my new.html.erb):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aaa").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/items/htmlupdate",
        data: {},
        async: true,
        dataType: 'script'
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

and create a method htmlupdate in my items_controller

```
def htmlupdate
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

and create a file htmlupdate.js.erb with the content:

```
$("#test_tag").html("qqq");
```

Now, nothing works. Why is that? Is there something wrong with my url: ... syntax? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you show routes related to that controller ? Also, does your browser javascript console say anything about an error ?

Comment: Hi Olivier, thank you very much for your response. Routing was the problem. I added to my /config/routes.rb:
get 'items/htmlupdates' => 'itmes#htmlupdates'
and it is working now. BUT WHY? I already had the following line in my routes.rb which should have had the same routing:
resources items, only[:new, :htmlupdates, :create]
Why resources wouldn't do the job? I'm really confused. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, the action names you can pass to `:only` or `:except` are only the standard crud actions (:index, :new, :create, :update, :delete), any other is ignored. The correct way to add custom actions in a resource is to do so in a block passed to the resource : `resources :items do; get 'htmlupdates'; end`